# Populate JSON file data into Array then feed Array into mmenu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, mmenu

I am trying to read a JSON file(menu.json) to an array(myList) in order to run a function(PopulateRecords) that will populate my jQuery menu plugin with lines of HTML. This ideally would allow me to dynamically change my menu options by only having to update the JSON file later.

**My JSON file is menu.json:**

```
{"pavers":
[
    {"display": "Brukstone", "url": "brukstone.html"},
    {"display": "Bulovar", "url": "pavers/bulovar.html"},
    {"display": "Cobble", "url": "pavers/cobble.html"},
    {"display": "Cracovia", "url": "pavers/cracovia.html"},
    {"display": "Filtrapave", "url": "pavers/filtrapave.html"},
    {"display": "Holland", "url": "pavers/holland.html"},
    {"display": "Old Munich", "url": "pavers/oldmunich.html"},
    {"display": "Strassen Classic", "url": "pavers/strassen.html"},
    {"display": "Strassen Bavaria (Tumbled)", "url": "pavers/strassenbavaria.html"},
    {"display": "Strassen Barvaria II (Non-tumbled)", "url": "pavers/strassenbavariaii.html"},
    {"display": "Vavel Stone (Tumbled)", "url": "pavers/vavel.html"},
    {"display": "Vavel Stone II (Non-tumbled)", "url": "pavers/vavelii.html"}
]}
```

**My HTML is**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
                <!--         -->
                <!-- Sources -->
                <!--         -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/js/jquery.mmenu.all.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/latest/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="import"
            href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box.html">

           <!--                                                  -->
           <!-- Attach function.js which contains PopulateRecords-->
           <!--                                                  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>

           <!--SETUP for jQuery mmenu plugin-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('nav#menu').mmenu();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#id01">Pavers</a>
                    <div id="id01"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            // CALL JSON DATA
            var myList;
            $.getJSON('menu.json')
                .done(function (data) {
                myList = data;
            });

            // POPULATE MENU ITEMS FROM ARRAY
            PopulateRecords("01",myList);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PopulateRecords function that is called is in a separate functions.js file that was attached in the html head.

**The javascript for the function is:**

```
function PopulateRecords(id, arr) {
    var out = "<ul>";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<li><a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].display + '</a></li>';
    }
    out += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("id"+id).innerHTML = out;
}
```

**How it should work:** The PopulateRecords function(called in `<script>` tag within HTML) should be passed the id number for the div element that is a placeholder(id01) within the nav menu HTML. It is also passed an array which is populated from the menu.json file (also called in `<script>` tag within HTML). It then injects html that follows the proper format that jQuery mmenu requires (list items and href).

**Note:** I have tested the PopulateRecords function with a declared javascript array successfully. So, the function works fine as long as it is passed a value for 'url' and 'display'.

*Naturally*, as I'm unfamiliar with the concept, this leads me to believe the problem lies in my inability to parse the JSON file. After slamming my head into this problem, I'm turning to the stack overflow community for assistance.

**EDIT: Ongoing-Debugging Notes**:

**1)** Below is the updated JSON call. By moving the PopulateRecords call into the '.done' the result stops the 'myList not defined error', but still does not populate the table (**img1** below).

```
var myList;
        $.getJSON('menu.json')
        .done(function (data) {
        myList = data;
        PopulateRecords("01",myList);
        console.log(myList.pavers);
        console.log(myList);
        console.log(data);
        });
```

[image: img1]
**img1**

**2)** I have also added several console.log calls to the '.done' for debugging. The log returns nothing when the page is called.

**3)** After the page is called, used the same calls in the console line for the page with the following results (**img2** below).
[image: img2]
**img2**

Comment: Could it be as simple as changing `PopulateRecords("01",myList);` to `PopulateRecords("01",myList.pavers);`?

Comment: This returns an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pavers' of undefined(anonymous function)".

Comment: Try putting  `PopulateRecords("01",myList);` inside the `done` callback.

Comment: The error is gone, but the menu items are not populated. I tried the proposed solution with mylist.pavers as well. Still no error, but menu items are not populated.

Comment: You should output `myList.pavers` and compare its structure to the array that the function worked with. That should help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I attached screenshot for output when interfacing with console to the original post under Ongoing-Debugging Notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you need to wait for the DOM to load before calling your function. Try doing

```
var myList;
$.getJSON('menu.json')
    .done(function (data) {
        myList = data;
        PopulateRecords("01",myList);
        console.log(myList.pavers);
        console.log(myList);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

which would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myList;
    $.getJSON('menu.json')
        .done(function (data) {
            myList = data;
            PopulateRecords("01",myList);
            $('nav#menu').mmenu();
            console.log(myList.pavers);
            console.log(myList);
            console.log(data);
    });
})
```

**FYI this is what I tried**:

html:

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<label id="menuTitle"></label>
<ul id="menu">

</ul>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('menu.json').done(function(data){
            $('#menuTitle').html(data.name);
            var lis = ''
            for(var i = 0; i < data.options.length; i++)
                lis += '<li><a href="'+ data.options[i].url+'">' + data.options[i].name + "</a></li>";
            $('#menu').html(lis);
        });
});
</script>
</body>
```

JSON:

```
{ 
    "name": "aMenu",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "option 1", 
            "url": "#"
        },
        {
            "name": "option 2", 
            "url": "#"
        },
        {
            "name": "option 3", 
            "url": "#"
        },
        {
            "name": "option 4", 
            "url": "#"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is heading in the correct direction for sure. It works as is, but this doesn't necessarily interface with the mmenu jQuery plugin or the PopulateRecords function. After class, I will fiddle with the solution to try to add those features and see if it keeps working.

Comment: @BillSmith I edited to include the `$('nav#menu').mmenu();` inside the .done after populating. It should work now, assuming you are using the plugin correctly :)