# Complex JSON nesting and accessing through loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I had a previous question answered here: [Populate JSON file data into Array then feed Array into mmenu plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160564/populate-json-file-data-into-array-then-feed-array-into-mmenu-plugin) which allowed me the ability to properly access all my JSON data, but only for one array. I want to make the code scale further, so I am trying to nest the arrays in order to accomplish this. I believe my issue lies with a JSON nesting issue and not with the loop function that is accessing the data.

Here is the **simple array solution that works:**

**HTML w/ Script:**

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
            <!-- Pavers -->
        <li><a href="#id01" id="menuTitle">Pavers</a>
            <div id="id01"></div>
        </li>

            <!-- Circles -->
        <li><a href="#id02">Circles</a>
            <div id="id02"></div>
        </li>

            <!-- Walls -->
        <li><a href="#id03">Walls</a>
            <div id="id03"></div>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('menu.json').done(function(data){
        $('#menuTitle').html(data.name);
        var lis = "<ul>"
        for(var i = 0; i < data.pavers.length; i++)
            lis += '<li><a href="'+ data.pavers[i].url+'">' + data.pavers[i].display + "</a></li>";
        lis += "</ul>"
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = lis;
        $('nav#menu').mmenu();
    });
});

</script>
```

**JSON File:**

```
{
    "name": "Pavers",
    "pavers": [
        {
            "display": "Brukstone",
            "url": "brukstone.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Bulovar",
            "url": "pavers/bulovar.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Cobble",
            "url": "pavers/cobble.html"},
        {
            "display": "Cracovia",
            "url": "pavers/cracovia.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Filtrapave",
            "url": "pavers/filtrapave.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Holland",
            "url": "pavers/holland.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Old Munich",
            "url": "pavers/oldmunich.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Strassen Classic",
            "url": "pavers/strassen.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Strassen Bavaria (Tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/strassenbavaria.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Strassen Barvaria II (Non-tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/strassenbavariaii.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Vavel Stone (Tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/vavel.html"
        },
        {
            "display": "Vavel Stone II (Non-tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/vavelii.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

My first thought and what I am attempting to do is to nest the data one level deeper in order to combine the arrays. After that I just nested the for-loop to make sure everything can be accessed.

**My *attempt* at nesting solution:**

**HTML w/ Script:**

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
                <!-- Pavers -->
        <li><a href="#id00" id="menuTitle00">Paver</a>
            <div id="id00"></div>
        </li>

                <!-- Circles -->
        <li><a href="#id01" id="menuTitle01">Circles</a>
            <div id="id01"></div>
        </li>

                <!-- Walls -->
        <li><a href="#id02" id="menuTitle02">Walls</a>
            <div id="id02"></div>

        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('menu.json').done(function(data){
    // IF SUCCESS
    alert('getJSON request succeeded!');

    for(x=0; x < data.object.length; x++){

        $('#menuTitle0'+x).html(data.object[x].name);
        lis = "<ul>"
        for(i = 0; i < data.object[x].links.length; i++){
            lis += '<li><a href="'+ data.object[x].links[i].url+'">' + data.object[x].links[i].display + "</a></li>";
        }
        lis += "</ul>"
        document.getElementById("id0"+x).innerHTML = lis;
        $('nav#menu').mmenu();
     }})

    // IF FAILURE
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); })

    //IF SCRIPT TRIED TO EXECUTE
    .always(function() { alert('getJSON request ended!'); });
</script>
```

**JSON File:**

```
{"object":
    [
        {
            "name": "Pavers",
            "links": [
                {
                    "display": "Brukstone",
                    "url": "brukstone.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Bulovar",
                    "url": "pavers/bulovar.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Cobble",
                    "url": "pavers/cobble.html"},
                {
                    "display": "Cracovia",
                    "url": "pavers/cracovia.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Filtrapave",
                    "url": "pavers/filtrapave.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Holland",
                    "url": "pavers/holland.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Old Munich",
                    "url": "pavers/oldmunich.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Strassen Classic",
                    "url": "pavers/strassen.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Strassen Bavaria (Tumbled)",
                    "url": "pavers/strassenbavaria.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Strassen Barvaria II (Non-tumbled)",
                    "url": "pavers/strassenbavariaii.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Vavel Stone (Tumbled)",
                    "url": "pavers/vavel.html"
                },
                {
                    "display": "Vavel Stone II (Non-tumbled)",
                    "url": "pavers/vavelii.html"
                }
            ]
        }
    ,
        {
            "name": "Circles",
            "links": [
                {
                    "url": "circles/bavaria.html",
                    "display": "Bavaria II Circle"
                },
                {
                    "url": "circles/cobble.html",
                    "display": "Cobble Circle"
                },
                {
                    "url": "circles/cracovia.html",
                    "display": "Cracovia Circle"
                },
                {
                    "url": "circles/strassenbarvaria.html",
                    "display": "Strassen Barvaria Circle"
                },
                {
                    "url": "circles/strassenclassic.html",
                    "display": "Strassen Classic Circle" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit:**

**1) 03/25/16 - 6:00pm CST**
The issue is the menu no longer displays when the button is clicked. So perhaps calling "$('nav#menu').mmenu();" at the wrong time. However, when I move it out of the '.done' function it will load the menu navigator without any content (besides what is explicitly defined in html). I would like the same functionality I had with the first solution, just extended to reach more arrays in a single JSON file.

**2) 03/25/16 - 7:30 CST**
Added error handling to script. Result returned: 
 1: "getJSON request failed! parsererror"
 2: "getJSON request ended!"

**3) 03/25/16 - 7:49 CST**
Reformatted JSON to be interpreted properly.. I was missing a '{'. Now receiving an error when

```
document.getElementById("id0"+xString).innerHTML = lis;
```

**Current Error is:**
brukstone.html:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: And what's the issue with your solution?

Comment: can you edit your problem description? use 1 short paragraph to describe what exactly your problem is, eg, what are you trying to achieve, what kind of data are you intending to process and what would be final outcome. put samples along the way

Comment: edit: moved to question.

Comment: There is definitely a `,` missing in your JSON, which could be the issue. Why don't you add an error handler to your Ajax call? That would at least tell you whether the problem is with the JSON or not. You know how to debug JavaScript code, right?

Comment: I admit, I am rather new to JavaScript. Do you have an Ajax debug reference I could read? I have been using Chrome dev tools, but that really only catches syntax errors. Note: trying the missing ',' first.

Comment: look at your browser console. see what kind of error msg is displayed (if any) when you make that ajax call to get your json data. the JSON file you pasted is indeed missing a comma as felix mentioned, but it might be a pasting error. it would be more accurate to look at your browser console to see if there are any errors

Comment: it wasn't the missing comma. I'm looking into ajax debugging now and will update the problem when I have output.

Comment: another question i have is that, when you call $('nav#menu').mmenu(); does it care about those id and attributes you have on your menu elements at all? or are those ids simply there for you to be able to easily select elements to operate on? remember to @username at the beginning  of your reply so that the other party will be notified by Stackoverflow that there is an reply for that person

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Yes, the id attributes are there so I can easily select my elements for operation.

Comment: in that case, i would suggest you to start with an empty nav container from start. and dynamically insert menu items as you parse your json

Comment: @Ji_in_coding I agree, and I will look into that later. I just added error checking and confirmed that it is a JSON parse error causing trouble currently.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for suggesting error handling. It is confirmed a parser error

Comment: look at the answer I have posted. it is the more jquery way of doing of getting things done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Here was the solution I was proposing to you. 
Since you have already decided to dynamically insert menu data. you might as well start with a completely empty `<nav>` element and dynamically insert everything into there.

Here is the sample code. It maintains exactly the same html structure as you are using.

[Play with it on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sc19he5/1/)

html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
  <!--
  <ul>
    <li  comment="this is a menu category">
      <a>This is the Menu Category Title</a>
      <div comment="this is the submenu container">
        <ul comment="this is a submenu list">
          <li comment="this is a submenu list item"> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  -->
</nav>
```

JQuery:

```
var data = {
    "object": [{
        "name": "Pavers",
        "links": [{
            "display": "Brukstone",
            "url": "brukstone.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Bulovar",
            "url": "pavers/bulovar.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Cobble",
            "url": "pavers/cobble.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Cracovia",
            "url": "pavers/cracovia.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Filtrapave",
            "url": "pavers/filtrapave.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Holland",
            "url": "pavers/holland.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Old Munich",
            "url": "pavers/oldmunich.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Strassen Classic",
            "url": "pavers/strassen.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Strassen Bavaria (Tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/strassenbavaria.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Strassen Barvaria II (Non-tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/strassenbavariaii.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Vavel Stone (Tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/vavel.html"
        }, {
            "display": "Vavel Stone II (Non-tumbled)",
            "url": "pavers/vavelii.html"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Circles",
        "links": [{
            "url": "circles/bavaria.html",
            "display": "Bavaria II Circle"
        }, {
            "url": "circles/cobble.html",
            "display": "Cobble Circle"
        }, {
            "url": "circles/cracovia.html",
            "display": "Cracovia Circle"
        }, {
            "url": "circles/strassenbarvaria.html",
            "display": "Strassen Barvaria Circle"
        }, {
            "url": "circles/strassenclassic.html",
            "display": "Strassen Classic Circle"
        }]
    }]
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    //this is the container for all the <li> that we gonna generate
    var $menuList= $("<ul>");

    //for each menu category
  for(var i=0; i < data.object.length; i++){

    //create a menu category
    var $menuCategory = $("<li>");

    //create a category title
    var $categoryTitle = $("<a>");
    $categoryTitle.text(data.object[i].name);

    //create a submenu container
    var $categorySubMenu = $("<div>");

    //create a submenu
    var $subMenuList= $("<ul>");
    for(var j=0;j<data.object[i].links.length; j++){
        console.log(data.object[i].links[j].url);
      console.log(data.object[i].links[j].display);

        var $submenuItem = $("<li>");
      var $submenuLink = $("<a>");
      $submenuLink.attr("href", data.object[i].links[j].url);
      $submenuLink.text(data.object[i].links[j].display);
      $submenuItem.append($submenuLink);
      $subMenuList.append($submenuItem);
    }

    $categorySubMenu.append($subMenuList);
    $menuCategory.append($categoryTitle);
    $menuCategory.append($categorySubMenu);
    $menuList.append($menuCategory);
  }

  //when the menu is fully assembled, append it into nav
  $('#menu').append($menuList);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution now works. Was missing a bracket and a comma on the JSON file originally. Edited Code in question to reflect working solution for anyone who may need a nested array JSON solution.